# Backbone collection counter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've  a collection witch can paginate over a collection in the backend, so onscroll I lot another batch of items. I know the count of items in on the server. I'm looking for a way to extend all my collections with a `getCounter` method. The idea is to set the server counter initially and when ever a user add or remove items from the collection the counter updates. Whats will be the best approach for this?

I think the problem is that the `add` event is also fired when I fetch new items from the server. Otherwise I could just bind to `add` and `remove` events.

Comment: create some kind of counter cache in callbacks of method you use to add/remove the item from collection

Comment: But then I have to do this for every kind of collection. I'm looking for something like a counter extension.

Comment: so write a mixin that can keep all the counters you want to keep. You need to keep it somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to control which additions and removals should count, and which not. Two options come to mind.

1. Silence all operations which should not count with the `silent:true` option, and hook up your counter to the `add`, `remove` and `reset` **events**. This will put some limitations to the general use of the collection, because you can't utilize their events in all cases.
2. Override the `add`, `remove` and `reset` **methods** to accept an extra option, which tells you whether the counter should be updated or not. Something like:

   ```
   var PaginatedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

       initialize: function() {
           this._counter = 0;
       },

       add: function(models, options) {
           if(options && options.count)
               this._counter += (_.isArray(models) ? models.length : 1);
           Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.apply(this, arguments);
       },

       remove: function(models, options) {
           if(options && options.count)
               this._counter -= (_.isArray(models) ? models.length : 1);
           Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);         
       },

       reset: function(models, options) {
           if(options && options.count)
               this._counter = (_.isArray(models) ? models.length : 0);
           Backbone.Collection.prototype.reset.apply(this, arguments)
       }
   });
   ```

   And pass the `count:true` option, when the added or removed item should be counted:

   ```
   var SomeCollection = PaginatedCollection.extend({ });

   var someCollection = new SomeCollection();
   someCollection.add(model, { count: true });
   someCollection.remove(model, { count: true });
   ```

(Code samples untested)

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but I think this isn't a good practice at all. Extending natural functions for this kind of purposes, mainly in your own code sounds ugly for me – mix your business rules with architecture design isn't the best way to go. Today, we have listeners that can deal intelligently with this behaviors for us... `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.increment)` is an example of how easy we can manage this problem. And yes, I know we're in 2014 and Backbone is now updatd, but I'm posting this for future apprentices and references.